# Mysql subquery with conditional left outer join

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

Trying to use parameter from external query in subquery FROM clause.

```
tbl1:
| id | val1 | str1 |
| 1  | 12   | sbc  |
| 2  | 22   | sds  |

tbl2:
| id | val1 | str1 |
| 1  | 1    | cp   |
```

Trying to write the following query:

```
select * from
    tbl1 t, (select * from tbl2 where t.id = tbl2.id and tbl2.val1 = 1) tb12;
```

Expected output:

```
| id | val1 | str1 | id   | val1 | str1 |
| 1  | 12   | sbc  | 1    | 1    | cp   |
| 2  | 22   | sds  | null | null | null |
```

Yet it fails with the error:

```
/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 't.id' in 'where clause' */
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl1 t
LEFT JOIN
        tbl2 t2
ON      t2.id = t.id
        AND t2.val1 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason not to use plain old left join like this:

```
select * from tbl1 t1 left join tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: I have updated the question, please note the fixed query to better explain the problem. I would like to do a "conditional left outer join"

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * tbl1 UNION select * from tbl2;
```

will produce the same result

Comment: No it won't because the requirements is lines from the left with match data from the right, if such exists. But not lines from the right that don't have a match from the left. btw, side note: This question was so interesting 2 years ago. Today it's a NoSQL world. Technology sure does moves fast...